# I am using regex (.*) to extract the following information but it's leaving half of it behind

Tags: .net, regex, regex-group

I am using refex (.*),\s- to extract the text "Foz do Iguaçu" below

I am using the format "DepartCity": "Diante do cenário desafiador que estamos passando, seu voo para **(.*),** Foz do Iguaçu  (IGU), no dia 01/03/2021,      foi cancelado devido a ajustes em nossa malha aérea.",

but it leaves the end of the text ie  (IGU), no dia 01/03/2021,      foi cancelado devido a ajustes em nossa malha aérea.",

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: All 4 of these characters have special meaning in regex `(.*)` so they should be escaped. Your content has no dash so `-` makes your regex useless. It seems you are trying to extract data out of a JSON string and that's a terrible idea. Use https://regex101.com/ to test your regex.

Comment: I am just using what seems to work. Nevermind if it's a terrible idea. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

As the commenter mentioned, you need to escape these special characters:

```
\(\.\*\), (.*)
```

Your first capture group will then contain the string:

> Foz do Iguaçu (IGU), no dia 01/03/2021, foi cancelado devido a ajustes em nossa malha aérea.

Try it out here: https://regex101.com/r/Gdwbh4/1

I'm assuming that you want to extract the entire remainder of the string after "(.*), ".

Also, you should not directly use RegEx on a JSON string. Instead, parse the JSON first to retrieve the values, on which you can then execute RegExs.